# How to load/show a referenced table twice (through another table and direct)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a projects model that's referencing to my users model in two ways: through a subscriptions model that's referencing to the projects model and a products model; and directly from a project.user-column to the user-id.

I'm using this construction because a project can have users that subscribes to a project, but it will also have an owner (for which I would like to use the same users model).

So:
a project belongs to a user
a project has many users through subscriptions
a user has many projects through subscriptions
a user has many projects

Especially this last has_many seems to give me some trouble (and I understand why, it probably conflicts with the one above it).

I'm able to show the subscribed users for a project, but not the owner. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this??

Project.rb code:

```
has_many :subscriptions
has_many :users, through: :subscriptions

belongs_to :user
```

User.rb code

```
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :projects, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :projects, through: :subscriptions
```

And this is the show.html.erb of the project

```
                <div class="center">
                <%= image_tag avatar_url(current_user), class: "circle responsive-img avatar-medium" %><br/>
                <h5><%= @project.user %></h5>
                </div>
```

And just to be sure, some code of my project-controller with which I load the subscribed users (don't know how to load the owner's name):

```
        if !current_user.nil? && !current_user.projects.nil?
        @joined = current_user.projects.include?(@project)
        end

        @users = @project.users.order('created_at desc').first(10)
```

Can anyone help me out?

I'm a Rails Novice who works in Rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the following change on the User model

```
has_many :owner_projects, class_name: 'Project', foreign_key: 'user_id'
```

At this point you have `#owner_projects` resulting in Projects where user_id is the User's id. And `#projects` which are the projects a User is member of

Comment: Thanks @Manuel, that looks promising! Do I have to rename my user_id column in Projects for it, or should I use a different method instead of: `<h5><%= @project.user %></h5>`
...or do I need to load owner_projects as wel in my controller?

Comment: After all, this was the perfect solution. It didn't seem to work because I connected non-existing user_id's to the projects ;)
Thanks for the help!